# Angular ngChange not firing in firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox, safari

I created a custom directive that works similar to Foundations custom dropdown. Basically I create a div and populate it with a ul with the options. Interacting with the div interacts with the actual select in the background. Eveyrthing works great in Chrome. The issue is when I select an option I use jQuery to trigger the change event for the select element. In chrome this in turn triggers the ng-change that is attached to it. For some reason this isn't triggered in Firefox and Safari. I would assume it should work the same as Chrome. I did some further testing and found that the change event DOES fire, but for some reason doesn't trigger Angular to fire it's ngChange method. I'm at a loss and need to get this done A.S.A.P. Any and all help is appreciated.

[update]

here is a simple code example

```
<select ng-model="model" ng-change="changeFunc()"></select>
```

I have jQuery installed so the directive give me the $element wrapped in jQuery so I simply call

```
$element.trigger("change")
```

In Chrome this in turn triggers the changeFunc on the controller

Comment: Any demo code ? fiddle plurk?

Comment: What if you use `changeFuc()` instead of `changeFunc`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. It is changeFunc(). I just don't get why firefox and safari seem to trigger the change event, but it doesn't trigger the angular ng-change!!

Comment: It may be linked with this issue from angular https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4216#issuecomment-25872117

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out. Apparetly you MUST set the selected option using:

```
element.selectedIndex = 0 // or the index that is selected
```

This sets the selected option and THEN you can trigger the change event using

```
$element.trigger("change");
```

SMH!!